# Export Java VisualVM .nps profiler data to excel

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

Is there any way to convert the .nps profiler data captured by [VisualVM](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/snapshots.html) to excel.

Namely I'd like to get a table view of the HotSpot Methods.
[image]

In the end I want to know if there's a way to automate the capture of VisualVM profiler statisitcs (e.g. command line script) and export that to Excel (CSV file or whatever), so that we could automatically upload it to say Google Docs spreadsheets.

It appears that VisualVM just uses the standard [HPROF](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) cpu=samples, but it's able to do it remotely I'm only aware of enabling profiling as a JVM argument. Is there some way to trigger that from JMX?

Comment: You mention that you'd like to get "HotSpot Methods" but you have the "Call Tree" section highlighted.  Which one would you like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a basic option in VisualVM when viewing the results to export to XML, CSV, NPS.

Comment: Where? I can't find it in 1.6.0_31.

Comment: Press "Export To..." button and choose file extension.

Comment: There's no such option. We can create an "Application Snapshot" though.

Comment: Perhaps there was such an option in earlier versions, but this answer seems outdated. There does not seem to be any way to export data in a plain format such as csv… (I tried on VisualVM 2.1.16)